# How to left join two queries in linq

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, lambda

I want to left join two queries. In that first query will contains 4 records and second query will contain 0 or more records up to 4. I want to join both these and want to get 4 records. If there are any records in second query then i want to the permission from the second table. I have written code like.

```
 var finalquery = values.GroupJoin(records, i => i.typeid, j => j.typeid, (i, j) => new { i, j }).SelectMany(i => i.j.DefaultIfEmpty(), (i, j) => new {
            id = i.i.typeid,
            Permission = (j.premission ==null)?null:j.premission

        }).ToArray();
```

But it is throwing an exception

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush null reference exception

Answer (score 0):

You have NullReferenceException on this condition:

```
j.premission ==null
```

That will throw when j is `null` (your default case).

```
var finalquery = values.GroupJoin(records, 
                                  v => v.typeid, 
                                  r => r.typeid, 
                                 (v, g) => new { v, g })
                       .SelectMany(x => x.g.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
                                  (x, r) => new { 
                                     id = x.v.typeid,
                                     Permission = r == null ? null : r.permission
                                  })
                       .ToArray();
```

Or with query syntax (converting to array omitted for beauty):

```
 var finalquery =
    from v in values
    join r in records on v.typeid equals r.typeid into g
    from r in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {
        id = v.typeid,
        Permission = r == null ? null : r.permission
    };
```

Comment: I have tried your code but i am getting the same exception. And what is the difference between my code and your code. Sorry for my language

Comment: @Pa1 well, initially there was not default value check in your code, and your code has bad naming for range variables. `i` is a anonymous object and `i` is a property of that object, and `i` is a value from values. BTW my code works fine with MS SQL

Comment: @Pa1 I found difference! You have exception here `j.premission ==null` when j is default

Comment: Thank you that worked. Instead of `r == null` i have compared `r.premission == null`